# Conditionally perform a lagging MAX and MIN calculation - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, lag

I have a table of data like so:

```
|   Order   | Step | StepStart |  StepEnd  | ProcessCode |
|:---------:|:----:|:---------:|:---------:|:-----------:|
| 103502090 | 6900 |  2-Jan-19 |  2-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 6900 |  1/2/2019 |  1/2/2019 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 6950 |  2-Jan-19 |  2-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 6950 |  2-Jan-19 |  2-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 7000 |  3-Jan-19 |  3-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7000 |  3-Jan-19 |  3-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 7050 |  4-Jan-19 |  4-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7050 |  4-Jan-19 |  4-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 7100 |  8-Jan-19 |  8-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7100 |  8-Jan-19 |  8-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 7200 |  9-Jan-19 |  9-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7200 |  9-Jan-19 |  9-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 7300 |  9-Jan-19 |  9-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7300 |  9-Jan-19 |  9-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 7400 |  9-Jan-19 |  9-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7400 |  9-Jan-19 |  9-Jan-19 |   PROCESS   |
| 103502090 | 7400 |  9-Jan-19 |  9-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7400 |  9-Jan-19 |  9-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 7450 | 10-Jan-19 | 10-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7450 | 10-Jan-19 | 10-Jan-19 |   PROCESS   |
| 103502090 | 7450 | 10-Jan-19 | 14-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7450 | 10-Jan-19 | 14-Jan-19 |   PROCESS   |
| 103502090 | 7450 | 10-Jan-19 | 14-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7450 | 10-Jan-19 | 14-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 7550 | 14-Jan-19 | 14-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7550 | 14-Jan-19 | 14-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 7700 | 16-Jan-19 | 16-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7700 | 16-Jan-19 | 16-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103502090 | 7750 | 17-Jan-19 | 17-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103502090 | 7750 | 17-Jan-19 | 17-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103561375 | 7450 |  4-Jan-19 |  4-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103561375 | 7450 |  4-Jan-19 |  4-Jan-19 |   PROCESS   |
| 103561375 | 7450 |  4-Jan-19 |  8-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103561375 | 7450 |  4-Jan-19 |  8-Jan-19 |   PROCESS   |
| 103561375 | 7450 |  4-Jan-19 |  8-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103561375 | 7450 |  4-Jan-19 |  8-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103561375 | 7550 |  8-Jan-19 |  8-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103561375 | 7550 |  8-Jan-19 |  8-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103561375 | 7700 |  9-Jan-19 |  9-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103561375 | 7700 |  9-Jan-19 |  9-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103561375 | 7750 | 10-Jan-19 | 10-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103561375 | 7750 | 10-Jan-19 | 10-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 6106 | 31-Jan-19 | 31-Jan-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 6106 | 31-Jan-19 | 31-Jan-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 6111 |  4-Feb-19 |  4-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 6111 |  4-Feb-19 |  4-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 6900 |  4-Feb-19 |  4-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 6900 |  4-Feb-19 |  4-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 6950 |  4-Feb-19 |  4-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 6950 |  4-Feb-19 |  4-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 7000 |  4-Feb-19 |  4-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7000 |  4-Feb-19 |  4-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 7050 |  5-Feb-19 |  5-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7050 |  5-Feb-19 |  5-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 7100 |  6-Feb-19 |  6-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7100 |  6-Feb-19 |  6-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 7200 |  9-Feb-19 |  9-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7200 |  9-Feb-19 |  9-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 7300 |  9-Feb-19 |  9-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7300 |  9-Feb-19 |  9-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 7400 |  9-Feb-19 |  9-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7400 |  9-Feb-19 |  9-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 7450 | 11-Feb-19 | 11-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7450 | 11-Feb-19 | 11-Feb-19 |   PROCESS   |
| 103561454 | 7450 | 11-Feb-19 | 14-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7450 | 11-Feb-19 | 14-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 7550 | 14-Feb-19 | 14-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7550 | 14-Feb-19 | 14-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 7700 | 16-Feb-19 | 16-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7700 | 16-Feb-19 | 16-Feb-19 |     END     |
| 103561454 | 7750 | 18-Feb-19 | 18-Feb-19 |    START    |
| 103561454 | 7750 | 18-Feb-19 | 18-Feb-19 |     END     |
```

The goal would be:

For every order, and every step in every order, calculate its **queue time** which is the time from the previous step's ***LAST END DATE*** to the current step's ***FIRST START DATE*** (the time this step was in queue to be performed).

> So basically, for each row Order and Step combination, I need to find
>   the last `END` date (when `ProcessCode = END`) and the first `START`
>   date (when `ProcessCode = START`). Then, subtract those two and report
>   back the value.

I have tried:

```
SELECT
    Order,
    Step,
    (MAX(StepEnd) OVER PARTITION BY (Order, Step) - LAG(MIN(StepStart) OVER PARTITION BY (Order, Step), 1, null)) OVER PARTITION BY (
    Order, Step) AS QueueTime

FROM
    thetable
```

But keep getting errors related to missing right parenthesis.

How am I able to write a query to achieve results like, for example, Step `7450` would be 1.
(These are actually `datetime` fields in the real database but when I edited some results it turned to just date)

Comment: I think the reason we need `LAG` here is because we are concerned with the previous Step, right? But is the `-1` always indicative of the previous, or just row number?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your syntax regarding parenthesis for over partition by is slightly wrong, should be:

`MAX("StepEnd") OVER (PARTITION BY "Order", "Step")`
`MIN("StepStart") OVER (PARTITION BY "Order", "Step")`

I have tried to fix your statement, see below:

```
SELECT
    "Order",
    "Step", 
    MAX("StepEnd") -
    LAG(MIN("StepStart"), 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY MIN("StepStart")) AS QueueTime
    FROM
  Table1
group by "Order","Step"
```

You can check my results here in a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f7a9/35).

Some useful examples for the Lag function can be found [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions). It seems it always needs an `order by`.

Comment: thanks, I will try this in the AM (it is late night by me) and get back to you...stay tuned.

Comment: This doesn't calculate anything for the previous step, so not quite right

Comment: I will need to check later this week. I ended up finding another solution, but I will see if this works. @Christian

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `MIN` and `MAX` analytical function as following.

```
SELECT
    Order,
    Step,
    MAX(StepEnd) OVER PARTITION BY (Order, Step) 
    - MIN(StepStart) OVER PARTITION BY (Order, Step) AS QueueTime
    FROM
    thetable
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This doesn't take the min for the previous row, step, just the current, so it still isn't quite right